# Handling MySQL Errors when using Ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, error-handling, submit

**Added header to the PHP code and the catch in the Ajax but still no joy.**

I'm having trouble getting my head around handling MySQL errors when using Ajax to handle form submissions.  I have the following code:

```
var url = "save.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#frmSurvey").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.


        success: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                $('.sequence-container div').hide().delay( 2000 );
                $next.show().delay( 2000 );



        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 503) {
                alert('Error: ' + jqHXR.responseText);
            }    else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                            alert('Requested page not found. [404] - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist.');
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                            alert('Internal Server Error. [500] - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                            alert('Requested JSON parse failed - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                            alert('Time out error - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                            alert('Ajax request aborted - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                        } else {
                            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText + ' - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                        }
          }

    });
```

This works fine and handles any erros such as pages missing etc.

However, I am completely stumped how to then handle/ display to the user any errors that might arise when actually submitting to the database.

Currently I've tried this:

```
if ($mysql_error!="") {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
                    printf("Unexpected database error: %s\n", $mysql_error);
        mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
        mysqli_clean_connection($link);
        exit();
    }
```

But as the page is not being shown (as it is being submitted by Ajax) the error message doesn't appear.  I think I have to bring that error message back into the Ajax script to display it to the user (is that right?) - and I'm not sure how to do this.

Any pointers/ suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move all your error logic from jQuery to PHP. You can respond with a simple JSON object that can hold the `status` (success or error), `code` (if needed), `message`, and even `data`, if you want to provide specific results.

For example, you make a request like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: $("#frmSurvey").serialize(),
  success: function(result){
    var json = $.parseJSON(result);
    if(json.response.status == 'success') {
      // do something
    } else {
      // look at message or code to perform specific actions
    }
  }
});
```

Then in the PHP file processing this request, you build an array with all the aforementioned elements you need (status, code, message, etc). Ultimately, you'll `echo` something like this:

```
$result = array(
  'response' => array(
    'status' => 'error',
    'code' => '1', // whatever you want
    'message' => 'Could not connect to the database.'
  )
);    

echo json_encode($result);
```

The `$result` array will contain the relevant data based on the checks you make in PHP.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply - appreciated.  I'm struggling to get my head around this - mental block.  I'm assuming I need to put a success as well as error in the array?

Comment: got it - placed the array in both the error and success sections of the PHP code, modified accordingly and it works a treat! Thanks.

Comment: One other note, I would make the error reporting more transparent to the user. Log the error and generate an email to you, then provide the user with a simplified message. All the user really needs to know is whether their request worked or not. If there's something *they* can do to fix it, you can let them know, other than that, a simple "We're sorry, but our application has experienced a problem" will do.

Answer (score 3):

Send a 503-Header

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
```

and your ajax-code should work.

**Edit:**
It will use your fail-code and you can check in the function for the status-code 503.

```
jqXHR.status
```

will be 503 and

```
jqXHR.responseText
```

will contain your message.

**Edit2:**
js.file

```
var url = "save.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: $("#frmSurvey").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.

success: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        alert('Error: ' + jqHXR.responseText);
    }else{
        $('.sequence-container div').hide().delay( 2000 );
        $next.show().delay( 2000 );
    }


},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404] - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error. [500] - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText + ' - Click \'OK\' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist');
                }
  }
```

});

save.php:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
echo('hallo welt');
exit();
```

result:

```
Uncaught Error.
hallo welt - Click 'OK' and try to re-submit your responses - if this error box re-appears, call 01255 850051 and we will assist
```

Comment: Hi Markus,  not sure what the above will do?  The Ajax code works and shows errors when pages aren't there - will the above help with handling `error` messages that are returned by `mysql`?

Comment: @Homer_J It will cause jQuery to enter the error callback rather than success since the status code is no longer 200.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - just wondering where it goes and then, how I still handle/display any messages coming back?

Comment: @Markus, ok that makes a little bit more sense - would it be something like `header: ('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');` - would this be captured in the success or fail section though I wonder?

Comment: I'm still unclear as to how it can bring back the PHP error message if there is an error submitting data to the database.  I'm utterly lost on this.

Comment: See the above edit - it's still not bringing back an error message.

Comment: @Markus - thanks for the reply and updated answer, sadly it's still not showing an error message. :-(